# Want to convert a function from Mysql to PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
function get_country($code){

$query = mysql_query("SELECT country FROM `list_countries` WHERE `code`='".$code."' LIMIT 1");
$country = mysql_fetch_array($query);

return $country['country'];
```

}

Very new to PDO and have absolutely no idea how to turn this from a mysql function to a PDO one. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Start by reading about `PDO`. Then try to use it. Then come back with questions about parts that are unclear. If you managed to hack this query with `mysql_*`, you must be able to do the same with `PDO`. As it stands, it appears as if you're after someone who will write the code for you. That's a no-no and that's not how you learn. Also, the code at php.net is almost copy paste, have  you even read about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take PDO database connection handler with you :) From your code I would suggest setting it as global, or you can add additional parameter to all the functions.

```
$dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db","your_user","your_password");

// this line is important - throw an exception if there is an error
$dbconn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

function get_country( $dbconn, $code ) {
    $res = $dbconn->prepare('SELECT country FROM `list_countries` WHERE `code`=? limit 1');
    $res->execute( array( $code) )
    $country = $res->fetch();
    return $country['country'];
}
```